# Display date format as April 2017

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, datepicker

I am inserting date and month only in database now the date insert **04-17** in this format

How to convert 04-17 to April 2017 ?

```js
$(function() {
  $('.monthPicker').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'MM yy'
  }).focus(function() {
    var thisCalendar = $(this);
    $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').detach();
    $('.ui-datepicker-close').click(function() {
      var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
      var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
      thisCalendar.datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="field-2" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Month</label>
  <input name="myDate" class="form-control monthPicker" required>
</div>
```

Image of view part
[image]

Comment: I fixed your snippet for you. What do you mean? You can take the value of the myDate field - it is "April 2017"

Comment: that working i will apply that code my own template  that did't show the view side

Comment: @antrooghosh how to convert mean ? to backend or frontend ?

Comment: backend. and frontend

Comment: convert means 04-17 to April 2017 to database

Comment: What is the column type of database?
If you are using date type it stores only format YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: the type is varchar

Comment: google developer tool console show :- Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function

Comment: Can you paste your scripts to below Javascript library files and then check?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://[::1]/varkala/index.php/admin/add_stud_attendance:222:33)
    at j (http://[::1]/varkala/resource/jquery.min.js:2:27244)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (http://[::1]/varkala/resource/jquery.min.js:2:28057)
    at Function.ready (http://[::1]/varkala/resource/jquery.min.js:2:29891)
    at HTMLDocument.J (http://[../resource/jquery.min.js:2:30257)

Comment: the above are error

Comment: Can you upload your template and code snippets?

Comment: got it i will add two files:-1)jquery-1.9.1.js  2)jquery-ui.js